# How to implement command history in Linux terminal?

Tags: shell, command-history, putty

I am using Putty as Terminal to connect a Linux server running Oracle Linux. To use a command multiple times, I have to type that command each time. There is no function of  Up and Down button unlike using Telnet from DOS command prompt.

Retyping longer commands or statements create problems. To overcome from this problem, I want to re-execute a command without retyping and use the Up and Down buttons.

- Is there any command which need to be executed to enrich the terminal
  with this functionality?

Comment: Linux default shell(`bash`) supports `Up` and `Down` arrows to redo commands. The same way you can search through your commands using the `Control`+`r` combination and typing a piece of the command you already executed.This is called `reverse-search`. This could be just a matter of configuring putty or the shell you are using on Linux. Those and other shell features long stand on Linux and BSD ecosystems.

Comment: Most Linux installations have working command history (that's the name of the feature you're asking for) by default. Your setup is weird. How is the account you're connecting to configured? What is the output of `ps uww $$; echo $TERM` and what appears when you press Ctrl+V then Up? What happens when you press Ctrl+P?

Comment: $ psuww $$
psuww: not found

Comment: $ echo $TERM
xterm
Ctrl+V then Up -> $ ^[[A

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking asking how to add command history to a program that doesn't support it, then use [`rlwrap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap).

Comment: Would you mind give your experience and some more details about `rlwrap`?

Comment: @Mohammed I've never used it. I just know it exists.